# Best way to connect to Azure resources via .net core 2.1

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-framework-version, azure-redis-cache

After converting .net framework 4.6.2 web api application to net core 2.1, performance issue observed, after profiling the code & taking timeline for the method calls invloved in a particular request/response most of the time difference observed in making I/O calls to Azure redis, cosmos, Azure Active directory. It seems old way of connecting to these remote resources in net core 2.1 doesnt seems to be efficient enough. Is there net core 2.1 recommended or latest way to connecting to Azure redis, cosmos, Azure Active directory? like connecting to Azure redis via EasyCaching rather than legacy way of using "ConnectionMultiplexer" for connecting redis.

P.S: At present Azure redis, cosmos, Azure Active directory connections are cached & reused where ever possible. Still making remote transactions using these cached connection taking more time in .net core 2.1.
Any suggestions or recommendations?

Below are the list of SDKs used .net core 2.1 project to connect to Azure resource like Storage table, blob, cosmos db, redis

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table Version="1.0.6" 
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob Version="11.1.1"
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core Version="2.9.2"
StackExchange.Redis Version="1.2.6"
```

Comment: Why would you bother to migrate from .NET to .NET Core and choose 2.1? Seems like for the hassle you'd just as well go to 3.1 which is also LTS. Here are [Performance tips for Cosmos DB and .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips)

Comment: Upgrading to 2.1 is management discussion but would to know like what would be the reason for performance lag especially why I/O calls from .net 2.1 project to azure redis takes more time than .net framework 4.6.5 project though same "StackExchange.Redis" v1.2.6 used in both the projects. Is there any other latest efficient SDK available? or any "guidelines to follow" to avoid perf. issue while connecting redis from .net core 2.1 projects?